# C++ wrapper function for Python's "list.count([character])" method?

Tags: c++, python

Is this a reasonable C++ wrapper function for Python's "list.count([character])" method?

```
int count( char CHAR, string STR ) {
    int counter = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < STR.size() - 1 ; i++  ) {
        if ( STR[i] == CHAR ) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
//Edited "for( int i = 0 ; i++ < STR.size-1 ;  )" to "for(int i = 0 ; i < STR.size ; i++)" now it counts the first char of the string =D
```

Tested it...works exactly like the python <3

Comment: you seem confused about what a wrapper function is. A wrapper function should call what it is wrapping, not reimplement it.

Answer (score 2):

When STR is empty, STR.size() returns 0u. As a result, STR.size()-1 becomes maximum value of unsigned size type. i++ < STR.size()-1. This will lead the function to crash.

Also your function will not count CHAR of the first character of STR.

You may want to use standard library.

[std::count(begin, end, CHAR)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/)  is just what you are looking for.

for example,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

...
char CHAR = 'l';
std::string STR("Hello World!");
ptrdiff_t counter = std::count(STR.begin(), STR.end(), CHAR);
...
```

Comment: Oh...im reading primer C++ n its pretty basic so i never even knew this existed in C++ :( do you have any suggestions on some great books/resources i can use to get myself up and coding in C++ the right way?

Comment: @BUCKSHOT - see this FAQ-entry: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1025391